# Replace character that match regex in python

Tags: python, regex

I want to replace some occurence of "," from my text. I do not want to replace all "," as it is a csv file. So for that i wrote regex where it identifies the text which contains unwanted comma. My regex101 link is below
    http://regex101.com/r/vF2iO5

It correctly identified my text from

```
 "_id" : "Java code PMD Complains about Cyclomatic Complexity , of 20", "tags" : "java   performance tuning pmd", "title" : "Java code PMD Complains about Cyclomatic Complexity , of 20", "results" : true, "value" : true, "processed" : true, "tokenGenerated" : [ "java", "code", "pmd", "complains" ]
```

Where it identified text in key "_id" and "title" which contains comma. Now i want to replace only these 2 comma in my text with some other symbol like "@@@". How can i do that??

My regex is

```
\"[(\w)(\s)]+ (\,) [(\w)(\s)]+\"
```

EDIT

Tried it in python with re.sub as  follows. But what am i supposed to write in replace part??

```
re.sub(r'(\"[(\w)(\s)]+\,[(\w)(\s)]+\")',r'\0',str(text))
```

Comment: Why don't you load it in Python and parse it?

Comment: @thefourtheye - i already tried it. Check my edit above

Comment: I was suggesting to read the file with `csc` module and then use string operations

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it using `re.sub`:

```
import re

s = '''"_id" : "Java code PMD Complains about Cyclomatic Complexity , of 20", "tags" : "java   performance tuning pmd", "title" : "Java code PMD Complains about Cyclomatic Complexity , of 20", "results" : true, "value" : true, "processed" : true, "tokenGenerated" : [ "java", "code", "pmd", "complains" ]'''

>>> print re.sub(r'(\"[(\w)(\s)]+ )(,)( [(\w)(\s)]+\")', '\\1@@@\\3', s)
"_id" : "Java code PMD Complains about Cyclomatic Complexity @@@ of 20", "tags" : "java   performance tuning pmd", "title" : "Java code PMD Complains about Cyclomatic Complexity @@@ of 20", "results" : true, "value" : true, "processed" : true, "tokenGenerated" : [ "java", "code", "pmd", "complains" ]
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do use sub

> > > re.sub(r'(\"[(\w)(\s)]+ )(,)([(\w)(\s)]+\")', '@@@', s)
> > >       '"_id" : @@@,  "tags" : "java   performance tuning pmd", "title" : @@@, "results"
> > >        : true, "value" : true, "processed" : true, "tokenGenerated" : [ "java", "code"
> > >       , "pmd", "complains" ]'